# How to show a node in a block in drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make frontpage and want to show a poll node on frontpage in a block. How can I do this? I have tried views but I am unable to find any way. how can I do this?
My second question is that how can I customize the css of the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install and enable the [Nodeblock module](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock/)

Once you've done that you'll need to edit your content type and enable nodeblock. Once that's done, any instances of the content type will be available as a block on the blocks page.

As for the CSS question [see this link](http://drupal.org/node/394612)